# Why did it take 7 years to divide the land?

Tags: eretz-yisrael, joshua--book-of, arachin-tractate

In [Arachin daf 13](http://hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=33&daf=13&format=pdf) it says that it took 7 years for the Jews to conquer the land of Israel and 7 years to divide it (in the days of Yehoshua). From what I understand they divided the land through a lottery system. So, what exactly took 7 years? If the land was already conquered couldn't they just get their assigned portion and go live there? What did they do over that 7 year period?

Comment: "Thank you for calling Acme Surveying Co.  Your call is very important to us.  Please remain on the line and the next available operator will be with you eventually." :-)  Seriously though, interesting question - thanks.